# Run python script on Raspbian desktop through ssh access

Tags: ssh, display, raspbian-buster, tkinter, raspberry-pi-desktop

I have a RaspberryPi with a PiTFT 3.5 display connected. The display is configured to mirror the HDMI output and the Pi is running Raspbian desktop.

Now what I am trying to do is to run a python program on the desktop but start it over the ssh connection. The problem is that when I just run my python script over the terminal as such:

```
sudo python3 /usr/local/project/main.py
```

it gives the following error:

```
_tkinter.TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable
```

So is there a way of starting the python program on the desktop through ssh or maybe passing the display variable to Tkinter so that the program displays on my PiTFT screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you launch the script from ssh:

```
export DISPLAY=:0
```

There are other possible values but, presuming there is only one GUI user logged in on the pi, it will be `:0`, the first display.  You can also get it directly from the desktop (`echo $DISPLAY`) -- but not from the `ssh` login.

Comment: Perfect it works, the only thing I had to change is to not run it as superuser and run your command and then it worked perfectly.

Comment: `$DISPLAY` is an [environment variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable#True_environment_variables), if you are curious.  The `export` command is a shell built-in.